# How can I override enumtype definition in Hybris?

Tags: enums, sap-commerce-cloud

There is a project for common logic, some enumTypes defined in this project's items.xml. But I want to define an enum with the same name in my extension project to override common enum, How can I realize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **extends** the enum you can use `generate=false auocreate=false` :

```
<enumtype generate="false" code="EnumToExtends" autocreate="false">
        <value code="NEW_VALUE"/>
</enumtype>
```

If you want to replace an existing enum with new values, you better create a different enum.

Note : `generate="false"` is not mandatory but it's often a good idea to set this property in order to avoid the `Generated..Constants` classes to be regenerated with the new enum value.

Comment: autocreate=false is sufficient as far as I know.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes you're right. But I guess most of the time you don't really need to have the value generated in your generatedconstants classes. If you take a look at hybris ootb example, you probably won't find a lot of `autocreate=false` without `generate=false`